Populate dates based on frequency
I am hoping to populate dates based on the start date and frequency up until the end date.
Input (this list will grow):



+
A
B
C
D
E
F




1
Start Date
End Date
Frequency
Cost
Category 
Company


2
02/02/2024
17/02/2024
14
545
Cow
First Farmers


3
03/02/2024
17/02/2024
7
23
Sheep
Outbacks


4
07/02/2024
17/02/2024
3
23
Pigs
Cowboys first



Making the output:



+
A
B
C
D
E




1
Date
Frequency
Cost
Category 
Company


2
02/02/2024
14
545
Cow
First Farmers


3
03/02/2024
7
23
Sheep
Outbacks


4
07/02/2024
3
23
Pigs
Cowboys first


5
10/02/2024
7
23
Sheep
Outbacks


6
10/02/2024
3
23
Pigs
Cowboys first


7
13/02/2024
3
23
Pigs
Cowboys first


8
16/02/2024
14
545
Cow
First Farmers


9
16/02/2024
3
23
Pigs
Cowboys first


10
17/02/2024
7
23
Sheep
Outbacks




I have worked out how to get the first row, but only the date using:
=ARRAYFORMULA( IFERROR( Sheet1!$A$2 + (SEQUENCE((Sheet1!$B$2 - Sheet1!$A$2) / Sheet1!$C$2 + 1, 1, 0) * Sheet1!$C$2) ) 

I made a EXAMPLE_SHEET so it may be easier to understand

Does this answer your question? How to get an array of dates of weekends following an input date from the same month with one formula in Google Sheet? The "idiomatic" way in Google Sheet to produce any sequence of dates (or something else) you want is to generate in excess and then filter for what you want. And that's covered in the other question. In your particular question, you can simply layer concatenate + sort on top of it.


Here's one approach you may test out:
=sort(let(Ξ,tocol(,1), reduce(Ξ,Input!A2:index(Input!A:A,match(,0/(Input!A:A<>""))),lambda(a,c,vstack(if(iserror(a&""),Ξ,a),let(x,offset(c,,1),y,offset(c,,2),Σ,quotient(x-c,y)+1,if(or(c="",x=""),Ξ,
 hstack(sequence(Σ,1,c,y),chooserows(offset(c,,2,,4),sequence(Σ,1,1,0))))))))),1,1,2,)



Thanks a lot mate, exactly what I wanted!

The following works.
=let(input,A2:A
    ,input_trimmed,offset(input,0,0,rows(tocol(input,3)))
    ,sort(reduce(tocol(,3),input_trimmed
                ,lambda(a,c,vstack(a
                       ,let(nrows,ceiling((offset(c,0,1)-c)/offset(c,0,2))
                           ,hstack(c+sequence(nrows,1,0,offset(c,0,2))
                                  ,arrayformula(if(sequence(nrows),offset(c,0,3,1,3)))))))),1,true))


Explanations
You already know how to generate the desired dates. And it's been answered a few times, including here.
The only thing of note regarding date generation (for future readers) is that it is better to do date+sequence(...) instead of putting start date within sequence(), which you already did. The former preserves the formatting in date while the latter does not.
Thus, the sequence of dates mapped from the first row is
=let(nrows,ceiling((B2-A2)/C2)
    ,arrayformula(A2+sequence(nrows,1,0,C2)))

Since you want a repeat of the rest of data, you can use if(sequences(nrows,...)) to get the repeat and the concatenate as follows.
=let(nrows,ceiling((B2-A2)/C2)
    ,arrayformula(hstack(A2+sequence(nrows,1,0,C2)
                        ,if(sequence(nrows),D2:F2))))

Here, a single arrayformula anywhere will prompt Google Sheet to display array outputs into adjacent cells.
Finally, you can use reduce to "loop" over your whole list of inputs, use vstack to concatenate them together, and then use sort to sort the overall output, which gave the initial answer.
The last thing is to enable indefinite range input. The input parameter of reduce and offset must be explicit Google Sheet ranges (instead of inline array). To convert the indefinite A2:A to a range with the right number of rows, we use offset(A2:A,0,0,...) because the output of offset is an explicit range. To get the correct number of rows, we can use tocol(...,3) to filter away empty rows. This last part is encoded as input_trimmed in the answer so you can see where it is. Though of course it is not re-used anywhere else and you can put the formula directly into the 2nd parameter of reduce.
Additionally, I used fixed numbers in offset so you can see more clearly what they mean relative to your current question. To make your sheet more robust, you can make the offset numbers relative to the actual columns, e.g. offset(c,0,column(B:B)-column(A:A)) instead of offset(c,0,1). That way, if you end up inserting new columns between the current column A and column B, the range references will update automatically.
